# android app popup button to another popup

Tags: android, pdf, popup

I am trying to create another popup from an existing popup. I don't want the first popup to go away either. My intent is for the user to insert values into a form (second popup) and return back to the first. I get an error: Unfortunately it has stopped. Here is the code that I have tried.

Main screen:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    position = report_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            startActivity(new Intent (NewCase.this,ArrestPop.class));
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

First Popup:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.arrest_popup);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .4), (int) (height * .6));

    agencyInfo_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAgencyInfo);
    arresteeInfo_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bArrestee);
    arrestInfo_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bArrestInfo);
    vehInfo_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bVehicle);
    bondInfo_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBond);
    drugsInfo_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDrugs);
    complainant_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bVictim);
    narrative_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNarrative);
    status_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStatus);
    saveArrest_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSaveArrest);
    cancelArrest_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCancelArrest);

    agencyInfo_Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    arresteeInfo_Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    arrestInfo_Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    vehInfo_Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    bondInfo_Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    drugsInfo_Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    complainant_Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    narrative_Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    status_Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    saveArrest_Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    cancelArrest_Button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.bAgencyInfo:
            startActivity(new Intent(this,AgencyPop.class));
            break;
    }
}
```

Second Popup:

```
public class AgencyPop extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.agency_popup);


    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.8),(int)(height*.6));
}
```

}

Comment: Please add error logs

Comment: I figured it out after going through it again. I forgot to add it to the main xml...